# How to insert TextBox into Grid when Window is loaded in C# WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{  
    for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        ColumnDefinition clDef = new ColumnDefinition();
        RowDefinition rwDef = new RowDefinition();
        clDef.MinWidth = 40;
        clDef.MaxWidth = 40;
        rwDef.MinHeight = 32;
        rwDef.MaxHeight = 32;
        grdAdtn.ColumnDefinitions.Add(clDef);
        grdAdtn.RowDefinitions.Add(rwDef);
    };
    TextBox[,] fields=new TextBox[8,8];
    for(int i=0;i<=7;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<=7;j++){
            fields[i,j]=new TextBox();
            fields[i, j].Text = "test";
            fields[i, j].Width = 40;
            fields[i, j].Height = 32;
            fields[i, j].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            //Grid.SetColumn(fields[i, j], i);
        }
    }
}
```

With this I managed to add rows and columns to grid but I don't see textboxes in grid fields. I need to make an array of textboxes so I can access them later and I don't know how to make control array in Visual Studio editor so I tried to make the array when application is running.
Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have commented out the SetColumn you need the following three lines:

```
grdAdtn.Children.Add(fields[i,j]);  
Grid.SetColumn(fields[i,j], i);  
Grid.SetRow(fields[i,j], j);
```

So you were on the right track you just hadn't added the text boxes to the design - all you'd done was create them and tried to set a column property.

Also note it's best to avoid single letter variables - row and col for example would make this easier to read.

There may be another way to approach the problem as a whole but this will get your code working